# PlayOnLinux using Anaconda python installation and can't find wxversion

Tags: python, playonlinux, conda

I have an installation of Anaconda in my home directory but it's giving me problems when I try to run PlayOnLinux. I get this error:

```
Looking for python... 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) - Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) - Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.6... 
Looking for python2... 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) - Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Please install python before trying to run this program
```

the python in my path goes to the Anaconda installation folder, which explains why just using apt to get the appropriate package isn't working. I think I need to either add the standard apt packages to my Anaconda installation somehow or make sure that when playonlinux attempts to run it uses the system python and not the Anaconda version. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of missing `wxpython` in newly installed anaconda python. You can install missing module by running `conda install wxpython`. No root password is required unless your anaconda based python has root level permissions.

`wxversion` module is a part of *wxpython* package and it checks for which version of `wxpython` to select during `import wxpython` if you've multiple wxpython versions installed.